# NamedNativeQuery JPA null primary keys exception

Tags: postgresql, jpa, eclipselink, sybase

I created a named query that looks like this with a result set mapping:

```
@NamedNativeQueries({ @NamedNativeQuery(name = "Q_INSTRUMENTS", query = "SELECT i.ID, i.TICKER, i.ISIN, i.SEDOL, i.NAME, i.COUNTRY_ID, i.CONTRACT_SIZE, i.EXPIRY_DATE, i.TYPE_ID FROM INSTRUMENT i INNER JOIN COUNTRY c ON i.COUNTRY_ID = c.ID"
        + " GROUP BY i.ID, i.TICKER, i.ISIN, i.SEDOL, i.COUNTRY_ID, i.CONTRACT_SIZE, i.EXPIRY_DATE, i.TYPE_ID, c.NAME HAVING i.ID = MAX(i.ID) ORDER BY i.NAME, c.NAME ASC", resultClass = Instrument.class, resultSetMapping = "InstrumentMapping") })
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "InstrumentMapping", entities = { @EntityResult(entityClass = Instrument.class, fields = {
        @FieldResult(name = "id", column = "ID"), @FieldResult(name = "ticker", column = "TICKER"),
        @FieldResult(name = "sedol", column = "SEDOL"), @FieldResult(name = "isin", column = "ISIN"),
        @FieldResult(name = "name", column = "NAME"), @FieldResult(name = "countryId", column = "COUNTRY_ID"),
        @FieldResult(name = "contractSize", column = "CONTRACT_SIZE"),
        @FieldResult(name = "expiryDate", column = "EXPIRY_DATE"), @FieldResult(name = "typeId", column = "TYPE_ID") }) })
```

and here is the class that is annotated with this named query

```
public class Instrument extends ManagedEntityBase{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(length = 10)
    private String ticker;

    @Column(length = 30)
    private String isin;

    @Column(length = 10, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String sedol;

    @Column(length = 60, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "COUNTRY_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private long countryId;

    @Column(name = "TYPE_ID", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private byte typeId;

    @Column(name = "CONTRACT_SIZE", nullable = false)
    private Long contractSize;

    @Transient
    private String contractSizeString;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "EXPIRY_DATE")
    private Date expiryDate;

    public Instrument() {
        // Default constructor
        this.contractSize = 1L;
    }

    ublic Instrument(String sedol, Country country, InstrumentType type) {
    this();
    this.sedol = sedol;
    this.country = country;
    this.type = type;
}

/**
 * Creates an {@link Instrument} with the given sedol, isin, country and type.
 * 
 * @param sedol instrument sedol
 * @param isin instrument isin
 * @param country instrument country
 * @param name
 * @param ticker
 * @param type instrument type
 */
public Instrument(String sedol, String isin, Country country, String name, String ticker, InstrumentType type) {
    this(sedol, country, type);
    this.isin = isin;
    this.name = name;
    this.ticker = ticker;
}

}
```

When I try to call the name query:

```
public static List<Instrument> getInstruments() {
        return DatabaseUtility.getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Q_INSTRUMENTS").getResultList();
    }
```

I get the following error:

```
[EL Warning]: 2020-01-31 15:55:40.732--UnitOfWork(1788318093)--Exception [EclipseLink-6044] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: The primary key read from the row [ArrayRecord(
     => 3000000002285
     => 00577
     => BMG8827A1045
     => BYX9N24
     => 13 HOLDINGS LTD, THE
     => 2
     => 1
     => null
     => 1)] during the execution of the query was detected to be null.  Primary keys must not contain null.
Query: ReadAllQuery(name="Q_INSTRUMENTS" referenceClass=Instrument sql="SELECT i.ID, i.TICKER, i.ISIN, i.SEDOL, i.NAME, i.COUNTRY_ID, i.CONTRACT_SIZE, i.EXPIRY_DATE, i.TYPE_ID FROM INSTRUMENT i INNER JOIN COUNTRY c ON i.COUNTRY_ID = c.ID GROUP BY i.ID, i.TICKER, i.ISIN, i.SEDOL, i.COUNTRY_ID, i.CONTRACT_SIZE, i.EXPIRY_DATE, i.TYPE_ID, c.NAME HAVING i.ID = MAX(i.ID) ORDER BY i.NAME, c.NAME ASC")
```

In the table the expiry_date is indeed null but this does not take part from primary key and by default the nullable value is true for expiry date. 
I use EclipseLink with PostreSQL. 
I try to migrate the current code from old Sybase to new PostreSQL. With Sybase datasource the error does not happen.

I tried using

```
<property name="eclipselink.jpa.uppercase-column-names" value="true"/>
```

to make sure the mapping to the columns is not made wrong, but it didn't fix my issue

Comment: Show us the `InstrumentMapping` class...

Comment: There is no such class. I used @SqlResultSetMapping(name = "InstrumentMapping"... this is already wrote in the question

Comment: Oh, my bad. BTW You have no `@Column` for your filed `id`...

Comment: I also had problems in the past with Java fields of the name `id` and its getter/setter...

Comment: Why do you specify the query to use resultClass = Instrument.class and resultSetMapping = "InstrumentMapping"? Should be one or the other, not both, as specifying the resultClass tells the provider to build the entity from the results using its normal mappings, which should be fine. The resultset mapping is if you have other columns or column names that are not in the mappings. If you execute the query directly, do the results come back using 'ID' as the column name or could it be returned as 'id'? this might also cause the 'ID' lookup to get null back.

Comment: The error shows a record  where the id comes 3000000002285 and all the others fileds are populated. Only expiryDate comes null, but it is not annoted with primary key and that's why I don't understand why the error says: "The primary key read from the row during the execution of the query was detected to be null"

Answer (score 1):

It seems that my question had its answer in it. The problem was due to wrong mapping for id. The mapping was done using "id" but the column in database is ID (capitalized). That's why I had null for id.

The solution was to put

```
<property name="eclipselink.jpa.uppercase-column-names" value="true"/>
```

in the right persistance-unit.